# Failure sending mail using asp.net. Connection host has failed to respond

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want to send a simple test mail from my c# application

I am using the following code

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from", "to");
mail.Subject = "TestEmailImportant";
mail.Body = "This mail is to test if this program is working";

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    UserName = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    Password = "xxxxxx"
};
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Send(mail);
Label1.Text = "Email Sent";
```

This is being triggered on the click of a button.

Whenever I click the button, the browser keeps "waiting for the host" and after a minute or so I get this error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond "some IP".

Pointing towards `smtpClient.Send(mail);` line.

Comment: is this correct "MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from", "to")"?

Comment: since you're using simple authentication make sure to allow your gmail account sender to allow less secure apps access. (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: Yes I allowed authorization for less secure apps.

Comment: repeat: is this correct "MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from", "to")"?

Comment: I think it is. MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromaccount@gmail.com", "toaccount@gmail.com");

Comment: Ok. I thought you're passing actual "from" and "to" strings instead of the actual email strings.

Comment: I decided to delete my answer and just post comments to your question. I just copied your exact code into linqpad and modified the from address to be my gmail account I have setup and set the to address to a personal email account I own. Set the credentials to my gmail account credentials and when I sent it worked. So your code is correct which leaves it to be something else.

Comment: My guess if you have an antivirus application that is blocking your connection from your machine. Try and turn off any antivirus or firewall you have enabled and see if it works.

Comment: I have put of the antivirus off and the firewall too. Still the same. Are there any other visual studio or IIS changes or configuration that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

sign up Gmail and go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps where you can see settings. 
Access for less secure apps

```
Turn off (default) ==> Turn On
```

after add this code,

```
  MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromm@gmail.com", "toaddress@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "TestEmailImportant";
                mail.Body = "This mail is to test if this program is working";

                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = "XXXXXX@gmail.com",
                    Password = "YYYYYYYY"
                };

                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                {
                    return true;
                };

                smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Gives an error: Error 3 Not all code paths return a value in anonymous method of type 'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback'

Comment: Tried again no errors but the same failure to send mail.

Comment: finally this one solution